# Change pageScroller offset for different window sizes

Tags: javascript, css, function, scroller, slicknav

For my site I use `jquery.pagescroller.lite.js`. In the .js file I inizialized the funcion like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // initiate page scroller plugin
    $('body').pageScroller({
        navigation: '#nav',
        scrollOffset: -195
    });         
});
```

Now, I need to change the scrollOffset value only if the window size is between 768px and 959px, leaving it unchanged for the other sizes.

**IMPORTANT:** Note that for those windows sizes the standard navigation (`#nav`) bar is replaced by a mobile navigation bar, with this code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#nav').slicknav();
});
</script>
```

I have **two questions**:

1. I noticed that the `pagescroller` script does not work when the mobile menu is displayed. How can I work around?
2. How can I call `pagescroller` inside my .css responsive file, in order to change the options? [probably the @Eric Whitehead answer will work, but I have first to make pagescroller to work for small window sizes.]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to insert a Media query for those dimensions

```
@media all and (max-width: 959px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    .dummy-tag {
        width: 255px;
     }
}
```

Then, in your javascript, wrap your pagescroller around

```
if ($(".dummy-tag").css("width") == "255px" )  {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // initiate page scroller plugin
    $('body').pageScroller({
    navigation: '#nav',
    scrollOffset: -195
    });         
 });
}
```

Comment: I tried but this doesn't work. I inserted your javascript code, adding an `else` with the other scrollOffset value, but it seems to consider only the else argument.

Comment: Don't use .dummy-tag, use an actual element that appears on the page

Comment: Also using an actual element (in my case the width of `.container`) it doesn't work